# R web scraping Amazon webpage

Tags: html, r, xpath, web-scraping

I try to scrape the information form amazon web page.
But the problem is there are 2 price tags of some product. The price locates in 2 different tags.

```
Example product 1 has price tag :  class="sx-price-whole" and 
product 2 has price tag: class="sx-price-whole"
product 3 has 2 price tag : class="sx-price-whole" and class="sx-price-whole"
```

If I extract the price based on the code

```
price = xpathSApply(check, "//span[@class = 'sx-price-whole'] | //span[@class ='a-size-base a-color-base']")
```

It gives me some products with 2 prices and I don't know which price belong to which product when i create a data frame. The length of the vector price is different with the length of the title of product.

How can I write a code that automatically take only one price when some products have 2 price tags. Please help me!

```
# Gathering data from mobile phone.
library(XML)
library(stringr)
library(RCurl)
baseURL = "https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_nr_n_0?fst=p90x%3A1%2Cas%3Aoff&rh=n%3A2335752011%2Cn%3A2407749011%2Ck%3Aapple&keywords=apple&ie=UTF8&qid=1519785465&rnid=2335753011"
handle = getCurlHandle(useragent = str_c(R.version$platform, R.version.string, sep =","), httpheader = c(from = "ed@datacollection.com"), followlocation = T, cookiefile ="")
check = htmlParse(getURL(baseURL, curl = handle))

class(check)
check

nextPage =xpathApply(check, "//a[@title = 'Next Page']/@href",as.character)[[1]]
originalURL = "https://www.amazon.com"
nextpage_link = str_c(originalURL, nextPage)

#extract the product info
productInfo = xpathApply(check, "//a/h2", xmlValue)
productInfo
class(productInfo)
length(productInfo)
  #write the function for extraction
  extract_product_info = function(x){
  info =xpathApply(x, "//a/h2", xmlValue)
  return(info)
}

#extract the image link of product
image = xpathApply(check, "//div[@class ='a-fixed-left-grid-col a-col-left']//img/@src", as.character)
length(image)
class(image)
linkImage = unlist(image)
length(linkImage)


# extract the price of the product
price = xpathSApply(check, "//span[@class = 'sx-price-whole'] | //span[@class ='a-size-base a-color-base']")
length(unlist(price))

# extract the star of product
star_div = unlist(xpathSApply(check , "//div[@class ='a-row a-spacing-mini']//span[@class ='a-declarative']//span", xmlValue))
class(star_div)
star_div
  #write the whole function
  extract_star_product = function(x){xpathSApply(x , "//div[@class ='a-row a-spacing-mini']//span[@class ='a-declarative']//span", xmlValue)}

#extract the number of ratef
numberofrate =xpathSApply(check , "//div[@class ='a-row a-spacing-mini']/a", xmlValue)
  #write the whole function
  extract_numberofrate = function(x){xpathSApply(x , "//div[@class ='a-row a-spacing-mini']/a", xmlValue)}

#extract the ASIN
ASIN = xpathSApply(check , "//div[@class ='a-row a-spacing-mini']//span[@class ='a-declarative']/ancestor::span/@name")
  #write the whole function
  extract_asin = function(x){xpathSApply(x , "//div[@class ='a-row a-spacing-mini']//span[@class ='a-declarative']/ancestor::span/@name")}
```

Comment: Try `(//span[@class = 'sx-price-whole'] | //span[@class ='a-size-base a-color-base'])[1]` to get the only price or the first one

Comment: @Andersson I tried but it did not work. It treats DOM as a whole and return the result as much as possible. In the html page, there are 22 products but it returns 33 prices.

Comment: You should do this not for the whole DOM, but for each `//li[starts-with(@id, "result_")]`

Comment: @Andersson I just want to say thanks for your help. I appreciate it alot. Finally, I can extract the price of the product.

Comment: Scraping Amazon is a ToS violation.

Comment: @hrbrmstr Hi, I just did for educational purpose, to understand more about xpath. I did not do it for commercial purpose. Amazon did not allow to acess their webpages through script method. But when I declared the information system of scraping method, they allowed me to get the html content.

Comment: The purpose has nothing to do w/whether it's an ethical and (in most jurisdictions) legal violation.

Comment: @hrbrmstr Thank you for reminding me. I will never do it again, I will do it on some web-scraping test site instead.